# Development build + Express.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

Разрабатывал фронтенд-часть через `vue-cli-service serve`, теперь стал делать бэкенд на том же NodeJS + Express.js. Столкнулся с той проблемой, что, используя `connect-history-api-fallback`, в качестве статических файлов нужно указывать готовую сборку приложения. Соответственно, при внесении любых изменений во фронтенд-часть приложения, приходится заново билдить проект, что не очень удобно.
Есть какие-то способы "подружить" фронтенд и бэкенд часть так, чтобы при внесении изменений в процессе разработки, происходила автоматическая сборка так же, как при разработке с помощью `vue-cli-service serve`? Например, чтобы development build собирался в отдельной папке и мгновенно пересобирался при изменениях в проекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue-cli-service build` имеет возможный флаг `--watch`, который позволяет пересобирать проект при изменениях. Один раз вызываем `vue-cli-service build --watch` и development сборка будет собираться при каждом изменении.